# How do i add variables inside a javascript line

Tags: javascript, arrays

im trying to add a json element to an array bul the issue is to get the element i have to use a variable in the middle of the line.

```
classid.push(Gjason.rgInventory.+ itemid +.classid);
instanceid.push(Gjson.rgInventory.+ itemid +.instanceid);
```

the '+' separates what i'm trying to add, i am aware that is not how it works. any help or links to topics explaining this would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
classid.push(Gjason.rgInventory[itemid].classid);
instanceid.push(Gjson.rgInventory[itemid].instanceid);
```

The brackets can be used instead of the dot notation when selecting properties from an object, but contrary to the dot-notation, the bracket notation supports variables.

Comment: cheers mate, you're a livesaver